# Pandas to_sql has error for a wide table: The identifier that starts with 'xxx' is too long. Maximum length is 128. (103) (SQLExecDirectW)

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of 232 unique columns that need to write to a SQL table. The keys are sensor data which look like

```
Index(['DMAnt[-]', 
       'DMCst[-]',
       
       ...
       'WRP[%]', 
       'WRD_S[rpm]'],
      dtype='object', length=232)
```

When I tried to create the table in SQL via the to_sql function

```
df_send.to_sql('Sensor_table', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

I receive the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The identifier that starts with 'DMAnt[-] FLOAT(53) NULL, DMCst[-] FLOAT(53) N' is too long. Maximum length is 128. (103) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Is this error complaining that the query is too long because of the many columns that I have? How can I get around this issue?

Comment: In fact it is the square brackets in the column name messed up the query, making it think I have a long column name. After I removed all [] it is now working fine. Thanks for the answers anyway as you pointed me to the right direction

Answer (score 0):

The error is mentioning the restriction that a SQL Server column name can only be 128 characters. You will need to modify the DataFrame column names to be under that length requirement.

Limitations in SQL Server:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Is it all the column names combined should not exceed 128 characters? I have 232 columns and that would be difficult to achieve

Comment: @JeffHo No, it is each column. SQL Server allows 1000+ columns per table.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that the column name is too long. Rename the column to something slightly shorter to stay under 128 characters and that error message should go away.

Comment: Is it saying all the column names combined is too long? How can I use less than 128 characters for names of 232 columns?

Comment: @JeffHo No, it is saying that one particular column is the issue. I pull in tables with 200+ columns. It's the length of the column name itself. There may be more but you should be able to see that and it will give you a new column name. `starts with 'DMAnt[-] FLOAT(53) NULL, DMCst[-] FLOAT(53) N' is too long.